# Customise space after \paragraph

Tags: spacing, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

This is a simple question but somewhat hard to search for, so it may already have been asked. What’s the easiest way to customise the spacing that appears after the `\paragraph` section heading so that the first paragraph is formatted more like the second?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Paragraph title.} Now for some text.

\noindent\textbf{Paragraph title.} Now for some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simple to to with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{*3.25}{*1.05}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\paragraph{Paragraph title.} And now for another text.

\noindent\textbf{Paragraph title.} And now for another text.

\end{document}
```

The last two arguments of `\titlespacing` use a simplified syntax:  for the vertical spacing with the previous text, `*3.25` means `3.25ex` with some stretchability and a tiny shrinkability.The last argument is the spacing with the text after the paragraph title, and `*1.05` also means `1.05ex` with some stretchability, but no shrinkability.[image]

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!